# Apis, arbiter elegantiae

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

A friend told me that the key to perfection is contained in this short poem:

> *I beheld a creature,
>
>   one bee regularly hovering speedily outside your courtyard, twirling elegantly like mermaids, that ravished me.
>
>   When three dark-grey wolves appeared, the tiny bee bolted!*

**What is the secret hidden in this idyll?**

Comment: idyll: (n) an extremely happy, peaceful, or picturesque episode or scene, typically an idealized or unsustainable one.

Comment: An idyll is generally a very short poem dealing with nature, that's why I used that term.

Comment: I'm assuming the bee is an electron and that the three dark-grey wolves are nucleons or quarks of some sort.

Comment: @EngineerToast http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idyll

Comment: I would argue that the difference between "a happy scene" and "a poem that describes a happy scene" is fairly small. I was just trying to save people a trip to the dictionary.

Comment: @EngineerToast apis means bee, not monkey

Comment: maybe of interest to you if you like this sort of wordplay: [cadaeic cadenza](http://cadaeic.net/cadenza)

Comment: @Spencerkatty Wow, that's beautiful! Thanks for the link, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> $\phi$, the golden ratio. The number of letters in each word (with $0$ represented by a line break) gives you the decimal expansion of $\phi$, namely $1.618033988...$

Comment: Wow, that was totally unexpected! I need to brush up on my mnemonics.

Comment: sometimes the speed with which you guys find answers seriously scares me

Comment: I was wondering at the hyphenated "dark-grey"... I guess 0 = line break? You should mention that because, as it is, your value for phi is wrong. [1.61803398874989...](http://oeis.org/A001622)

Comment: Dark-grey is 8, line break is 0

Comment: @Spacemonkey On a very good day I can answer 2 or 3 questions each within 5 minutes of posting! Engineer Toast, thanks - I noticed that later on but haven't had the chance to log in since I posted the answer.